# how to find the port number for wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf

i downloaded a wcf sample example from net. it have the following code in app.config file..

```
<baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
```

But when i attempt to run this project it is showing 8090 is unregistered.. so i need to find on which port number this wcf service is running.. how to find it
It is showing error message as below

```
HTTP could not register URL http://+:8090/MyService/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by port is "unregistered"?

Comment: Please come up with more clarification of your issue. Try to write formally.

Comment: No, you have to run it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the project, it should spawn a hosting service which will show up as an icon in your taskbar on the right side.  If you double-click on the hosting service icon, it should tell you what port it is running on.

Comment: ya, but for first time only it showing.. for second time that icon is not coming.